# Limit file size per user

Tags: linux, ulimit

I tried to limit file size per user. I use limits.conf with fsize size config but its limit when user tried to make files from shell !
I want to limit from FTP , FileManager , PHP ,... files owners are same as username.

Is there any way to limit files size per user to do not create files more than 10Mb.

Comment: I assume you mean 10 MB rather than 10 Mb. Do you want to limit each file to 10 MB (so if the user created 5 files that would be 50 MB) or to limit the total amount to 10 MB (so if the user created one file at 9 MB they would be able to create another one but only at 1 MB)?

Comment: @roaima I dont want to limit the total amount I just want to limit each file size to not exceed the 10MByte